# How to fix GET requests for "usmUserSecurity" in netsnmp?

Tags: snmp, net-snmp

```
snmpget -v 2c -c public myDevice usmUserSecurity
```

Returns:

```
SNMP-USER-BASED-SM-MIB::usmUserSecurityName.".q...s...."."__internal__" = STRING: __internal__
```

instead of NoSuchObject/Instance.
The same behaviour happens for all the other columns in `usmUserTable`.

Looks like the `get` requests act as `getNext` in this case. I am trying to fix this, but I can't seem to find the relevant part of code ( in the net-snmp code base ) which deals with these requests.  Can someone assist?

Answer (score 0):

You'd better capture the network packets and then see if the captured packets are special. As Net-SNMP is so "old" and stable, it is least likely that you discover a new bug.